# What is causing putty to not connect to beaglebone black

Tags: networking, windows-8, putty, beagleboneblack

I have a Beaglebone Black(rev c),I am trying to connect it to `Windows 8` laptop using `putty`. I am putting IP address as `192.168.7.2` and port as `22`,but when I says open to it,putty window will pop-up and after sometime I will get fatal ERROR saying:

```
"Network connection time-out"
```

I am new to this, can someone tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to indicate the an `SSH server` is not running on the BBB. Or possibly for some reason the BBB did not take `192.168.7.2` as an `IP`. Or perhaps you might need to wait a little bit longer for the SSH server to start up.

Short of this, there is not much to go on. One way to trouble shoot the issue would be  to get a `serial debug cable`, connected and working to the BBB. Then you could `dmesg | grep ssh` or some such and hopefully get closer to what the actual problem is. Sorry if this is not enough for you to go by, but it is really hard to figure out what is going on without more information.

Other potential problems could be as simple as a `USB cable` that sometimes works or sometimes doesn't.

Comment: In my case the issue was actually trusting the cheap USB cable that came with the package. Changing to another known working cable did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be this but have you installed the drivers? See step 2 here: http://beagleboard.org/getting-started. If it's not that or you have already installed those then I am not sure sorry. Perhaps someone else has another suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have already installed a driver.

Answer (score 1):

Is the BeagleBone connected to your network with an Ethernet cable? It will only use 192.168.7.2 for the network-over-usb when there's only a USB cable connected - if you have Ethernet connected it will use DHCP to get an IP from your router, in which case you can check your router page to see what IP it got.

If you do just have USB connected then a driver issue is the most likely culprit, but you could try to ssh to the hostname `beaglebone.local` instead of the IP.

Comment: I am using USB only.I have checked with other windows pc which doesn't have antivirus, its working over there. It seems to be firewall settings issue.